# Socket.io does not work when to an Android 10.0 device

Tags: android, socket.io

I created an app that makes a socket.io connection to my server.

When I use my cell phone (with android 6.0) it connects normally.
When I run the same app on an emulator(genimotion) with android 10.0 the connection to the server is not made

I believe they are the permissions of the application, but in my **AndroidManifest** I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.group">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Group">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My java class **Conexao**, it creates a socket and through the **open()** method it connects to the server:

```
package com.example.group;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;


public class Conexao {
    private String host = "http://192.168.0.117:8090";
    Socket socket;

    public Conexao() throws URISyntaxException {
        socket = IO.socket(host);
    }
    public void open(){
        socket.connect();
    }
    public void close(){
        socket.disconnect();
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.group;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import com.example.group.Conexao;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Conexao conexao = null;
        try {
            conexao = new Conexao();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        conexao.open();
    }
}
```

**SplashScreen.java@onCreate:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        },3000);
    }
```

On my cell phone (Android 6.0) I get the connection.

In the emulator (Android 10.0) I do not get the connection.

What could be causing this situation?

Comment: have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63047727) before?

Comment: omg!!! bro this was what caused the problem, I don't believe lol, thank you very much, it helped a lot

Comment: I followed what it said in the link, I chose to add **android: usesCleartextTraffic = "true"** in the **<application>** tag(as app it is still a trial version ) and it worked like magic rs.
The sad thing will be having to pay for SSL in the future rs ;-;